# Sum the product of every 2 cells in a row (sum of A1*B1, C1*D1, E1*F1...to end) in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

[image]

I want to find the average share price in B4 based on the table of shares purchased and price seen to the right. Each meeting we will buy a few shares at different prices. I need a formula for B4;B8 that will basically do the function =sum(e4*f4,g4*h4,i4*j4...to end)/c4. Obviously I can do it manually with the given formula but I was hoping there would be an easier way to update the average share price when the # of new shares bought and the purchased price are entered after future meetings. Any idea if/how this can be done?

Comment: Just to zoom out a bit, I'll mention that if your data was normalized, i.e., each row applied to just one purchase, you could then analyze the heck out of it with a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

With data in the first row only, in **A2** enter:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(COLUMN()),0,INDEX($1:$1,1,COLUMN())*INDEX($1:$1,1,COLUMN()+1))
```

and copy across until data ends in the top row.

Then use:

```
=SUM(2:2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In B4 use,

```
=sumproduct((D4:I4)*(E4:J4)*mod(column(D:I), 2))/C4
```

Fill or copy down.

[image]